# ZeroMQ: Can subscribers publish?

Tags: node.js, zeromq

I am trying to implement an idea I have for a pub/sub app I'm doing in Node.js with 0mq. I want to use the publishing of messages as a kind of event system.

Here's an example: Say I have a publisher and two subscribers.

The publisher sends a message whenever a file is changed:

```
//publisher.js
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs'),
      zmq = require('zmq'),

// create publisher endpoint
publisher = zmq.socket('pub'),

filename = 'target.txt';

fs.watch(filename, function(){
  // send message to any subscribers
  publisher.send('files changed');
});

// listen on TCP port 5432
publisher.bind('tcp://*:5432', function(err) {
  console.log('Listening for zmq subscribers...');
});
```

Subscriber #1 logs everything that happens to the console:

```
//subscriber1.js
'use strict';

const zmq = require('zmq'),
      subscriber = zmq.socket('sub');

// subscribe to all messages
subscriber.subscribe('');

// handle messages from publisher
subscriber.on("message", function(data) {
    console.log('Got a message: ' + data);
});

// connect to publisher
subscriber.connect("tcp://localhost:5432");
```

Subscriber #2 validates the changes to the file and sends a message to let us know that it looks ok:

```
//subscriber2.js
'use strict';

const zmq = require('zmq'),
      subscriber = zmq.socket('sub');

// subscribe to all messages
subscriber.subscribe('');

// handle messages from publisher
subscriber.on("message", function(data) {
    //pretend I did some work here

    subscriber.send('File looks great!');
});

// connect to publisher
subscriber.connect("tcp://localhost:5432");
```

What I'd expect is that sending a message back through the socket from subscriber 2 would forward it on to subscriber 1, who would log it. But that doesn't seem to be happening.

I am probably fundamentally misunderstanding pub/sub, but is it possible to do what I'm talking about? If so, do I need to use a different pattern, or am I just using the zmq API wrong?

Comment: A subscriber -- as the name implies -- can't publish anything.  If you want to *send* messages you need a different type of socket (your own publisher sock, or set up a REQ/REP pair, or something else...).  It is common for a ZMQ application to use multiple sockets of different types.

Comment: So then, could my subscriber2.js create a new publish socket, send a message, then destroy the publish socket? Would that be the right way to do it?

Comment: Actually, just tried that, it didn't work. So now I'm wondering, do I need some other kind of socket in subscriber2.js? A router or a dealer maybe? Is it common to have multiple sockets subscribed to multiple other sockets? So my code will have to manage subscriptions between these sockets?

Comment: Or maybe I need this: http://netmq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/xpub-xsub/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do a little extra plumbing to get the results I was looking for.

Had to add a publisher socket to subscriber-publisher.js, and publish from it to a different port. Then I had to subscribe subscriber.js to the two ports published by publisher.js and subscriber-publisher.js.

So now I understand that in order to do this with pub-sub, I have to build more sockets, and must do a bit more manual subscription the I thought.